# Split flat file destination for every 100 rows into a new file

Tags: sql-server, ssis, flat-file

I currently have a dataflow task which has a OLEDB source, and a flat file destination.

I now have to modify this to create a flat file as it has now, but for every 100 rows create a new file.

So if there are 250 rows in total, I would have to create 3 files.

```
file1.txt  // contains rows 1-100
file2.txt  // 101-200
file3.txt  // 201-250
```

The number of rows is dynamic, I don't know before hand how many rows/files I will have to create.

What options do I have?

I am using VS 2008 for this project.

Comment: It's times like these, that unix is handy. Either way, the SSIS way will be either 1) A Script Destination in your data flow that does all the write to file activity. Great for flexibility, but murder on maintainable because you aren't using the "native" destination. 2) Use a normal flat file destination, file.txt and then have an Execute Script Task after the DFT and then do the file splitting there. I'd likely go with #2 myself, easier to debug

Comment: @billinkc are you referring to a 'script component'?  This is vs 2008 I don't see a script task.

Comment: "Script Components" are what you add to a dataflow.   "Script Tasks" are what you add to a control flow.

Comment: @TabAlleman Yes, but did he actually mean to use a script component inside of my dataflow after the flat file destination or a script task?  Not sure I understand how things would be setup in SSIS using a script task.

Comment: A Script Component, which is inside the dataflow task, acting as a Destination. When you add it to the Data Flow, it asks whether you'd like for it to behave as a Source, Transformation or Destination and my fingers shortened it to Script Destination. Apologies on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do something similar to this in a script task:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        string var_FileSource = Dts.Variables["var_FileSource"].Value.ToString();
        string baseName = var_FileSource + "file_";

        StreamWriter writer = null;

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader inputfile = new System.IO.StreamReader(var_FileSource + "P:\txt"))  
            {

                int count = 0;
                int filecount = 0;
                string line;

                while ((line = inputfile.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    if (writer == null || count > 99)
                    {
                        count = 0;
                        if (writer != null)
                        {
                            writer.Close();
                            writer = null;
                        }
                        ++filecount;
                        writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(baseName + filecount.ToString() + ".txt", true);
                    }
                    writer.WriteLine(line);

                    ++count;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }

        finally
        {
            if (writer != null)
                writer.Close();
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

This script should break the target files into 100 row subfiles, similar to what you want.  I'm sure a C# expert could suggest some improvements.

Edit:  Also change all of the paths to variable references, as well as the count value where you split the file.  It will make future changes much easier.

Comment: How will this look in SSIS.  I currently have a dataflow task that does OLEDB -> Flat file destination.  Where would your script task fit in this picture?

Comment: After your dataflow task executes, you would call this script task that would split the created file for you.  You would probably want a file system delete task that will delete the original file when it is done, as well.